# Implementing Undirected Weighted Graph

Tags: graph

I want to know what will be an efficient way to implement an undirected weighted graph. I want to perform Prims and Kruskal algorithms on it. I know about adjacency lists but wouldn't that waste memory; for eg. lets suppose I have two vertexes A and B connected by an edge with weight 'x', so I'll need to add two entries in the adjacency list:

```
A,B,x
B,A,x
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Adjacency lists are the memory-efficient way of implementing graphs, rather than adjacency matrices.

Actually, you have two options here.

- If you want less time and more memory, you should do what you've written.
- If you want more time and less memory, you could implement your edges `A,B,x` where `A>B`. But then, you would spend a lot of time while getting the adjacent vertices of any vertex.

It's your call. But second bullet is not preferred if you're dealing with less than millions of nodes.

Answer (score 0):

since the graph is **undirected** I guess you will need only **one** edge between the nodes A and B